# Dockerfile - Laravel acceder mediante subdominio

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, docker, laravel-6, docker-compose

tengo un proyecto con **laravel** dockerizado, si ejecuto el comando "php artisan serve" me lanza un servidor en http://localhost:8080 y puedo acceder a el perfectamente, pero no quiero eso quiero poder acceder por nombre mediante "**api-cars.local**"

Mi pregunta es si tengo este proyecto en laravel en un contenedor docker, como puedo hacer para que me resuelva este nombre "api-cars.local"

El archivo **Dockerfile** que tengo es este

```
    FROM php:7.4.1-apache

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        apt-utils \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
        vim \
        nano \
        fonts-liberation \
        fonts-liberation2 \
        fonts-arkpandora \
        xfonts-base \
        fonts-indic \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && docker-php-ext-install session

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
   apt-get install -y nodejs \
   npm

COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

Y el contenido del fichero **vhost.conf** es este

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    ServerName api-cars.local
    ServerAlias www.api-cars.local

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

A pesar de hacer esto, si intento acceder desdel navegador a http://api-cars.local me da error.

Adjunto **docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: laravelapp
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    command: sh ./devops/deploy_local_docker.sh
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    extra_hosts:
      - "api-cars.local:127.0.0.1"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SQL_HOST=db
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laraapp_db
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_HOST=
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    mysql_data:
```

Gracias,

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar el docker-compose.yml? ¿Estás usando windows o linux?

Comment: Estoy en windows, lo adjunto en el post principal. Gracias

Comment: Yo lo que haría es añadir a `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` el host `api-cars.local` apuntanto a 127.0.0.1. Si eso no te vale aquí hay unas cuantas soluciones un poco más enrevesadas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070547/how-to-expose-a-docker-network-to-the-host-machine

Comment: Gracias, al final lo solucione añadiendolo al archivo hosts de windows, el tema esta que yo queria acceder al puerto 8080 redireccionado al 80, al final lo que hago que para mi es más comodo es acceder a api-cars.local:8080 y de esta forma se que estoy por docker

Comment: Si lo quieres abrir el puerto 80 puedes hacer esto: `ports - "80:8080"`. Lo único tener en cuenta que los puertos que se expongas en los contenedores (parte izquierda antes de los dos puntos) se abren en la máquina anfitriona, por lo que si tienes otro servidor web con el puerto 80 abierto no vas a poder hacerlo. O paras el servidor web, o le cambias de puerto o utilizas otro puerto en el contenedor.